# Does react-leaflet support a non-default CRS?

Tags: react-leaflet

As far as I can tell, [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet), does *not* support using a coordinate reference system (CRS) other than [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)'s default (EPSG:3857). Is this the case?

[`react-leaflet`'s documentation](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/tree/master/docs#react-leaflet-documentation) contains no references to CRS.

From what I see [in the source](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Map.js#L66), the `Map` component passes props through, but it's not obvious to me whether it would work (or whether it's a "good idea"TM) to instantiate a `Leaflet.CRS` out-of-band and pass that through.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've answered your own question.  As you note, the props get passed through to Leaflet's map function which does support a [custom CRS](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-crs).  It's probably not a good idea unless you know how you will use the custom CRS.